Karate - how to identify function argument is locator name or string?
I have a re-usable function to check string. Is there anyway that I can check in Karate whether the argument is name of locator or string?
e.g.
* def I_Check_String_ = 

"""function(locatorOrString, stringToCompare){
         //Check locatorOrString
         if(locatorOrString == locator){
             Do comparing accordingly
         }else{
             Do comparing accordingly
         }     
}
"""

Please advise.
Thank you!

sorry I think this is up to you to design when you write the re-usable function, otherwise I don't understand your question
